# "In the beach" vs. "In beach"

Tags: articles

What are  the differences between the following sentences? If I wanted to talk about  *the* beach in general, which would be more appropriate?

> 1. I love playing in beaches
> 2. I love playing in beach.
> 3. I love playing in the beaches.
> 4. I love playing in the beach.

Comment: What would be the "correct preposition *and* differences"?? How can you have a "correct difference" ? The OP did NOT ask about prepositions, the user who replied provided that information.

Comment: @Rathony you're usually very quick to write a meta post condemning someone's edit, or someone's poor answer, but I'm getting a little weary of seeing your well-intentioned but sometimes careless edits. Should I write a meta post?

Comment: If the user was unsure *which* preposition to use they would have said so, or provided examples with "on", "at", "onto" etc. You're joining the terms *preposition* and *differences* with "and". If you had read the OP's comments, you would have seen the OP is concerned about articles, hence the different examples with and without the article.

Comment: @Rathony please ask the community and write up a meta post. I shall leave my comments up. P.S I deleted one comment, but the mods can read deleted comments. EDIT: I don't do chat because conversations are not private.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34006/discussion-between-rathony-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please join the chat room

Comment: @Mari-LouA What is the difference between your edit and my edit? Your edit doesn't have the question about using an article. The below answer starts with "The correct preposition is on the beach". I used "among" and you used "between". Why are you doing this to other users?

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you find an edit which doesn't look good based on your style/preference/grammar, please don't hesitate to edit it yourself. I believe that is the policy and guideline encouraged by this community. If you start nit-picking all the errors of all the edits/questions/answers in this site, how many do you think we can find?

Comment: @Mari-LouA What is your opinion about [this edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298353/sphere-vs-domain)? Do you think it is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

The correct preposition is *on* the beach. *At* is also used, but not *in*.

> <s>I love playing on beach.</s>

This is not correct, because *beach* cannot normally be used as a non-countable noun (unlike *sand* or *water*). You normally cannot use a countable noun without any article, except when it's plural.

---

> I love playing on the beach.

This is a general statement: it applies to all beaches around the world.

---

> I love playing on beaches.

This is also a general statement. It has a slightly different connotation from *on the beach*: the plural word suggests that you have played or want to play on several different beaches. In practice, it means the same thing as *on the beach*. But it is less common; *on the beach* is the normal way of saying what you want to say.

---

> I love playing on the beaches.

This is unusual. It means that you are referring to several specific beaches that must have been mentioned or are known to your public. Normally, you would not say this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Articles often make me confused since I speak with language which articles aren't used.

Comment: *At* is also a natural and acceptable preposition.